# What does "a function is minorised" mean?

Tags: terminology, regularization

I'm reading a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.afm/1485898519) about Lasry-Lions regularisation.
In Theorem 1 of the paper, considered function $f$ is assumed to be minorised.

What does it mean?

EDIT: Is it equivalent to "bounded below"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the range of $f$ has a lower bound. In other words, there is some $L\in\Bbb R$ such that$$(\forall x\in X):f(x)\geqslant L.$$

Comment: How do you know this is the correct definition? I know what it means to say that "[$f$ minorizes $g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135312/what-does-minorize-mean#:~:text=1,means%20%22bound%20from%20above%22.)" but I haven't heard the phrase "$f$ is minorized" before. I would have guessed it means something like "$f$ is minorized by some function $g$ that satisfies such and such properties" (perhaps $g$ should be affine or something).

Comment: Because “minorant” means “lower bound” and because the autor of that article writes that “the method has the pleasant feature that it preserves the infimum of $f$”. If $f$ had no lower bound, it would have no infimum.